# Cannot create temp file error (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I am currently using Vagrant and Virtual Box for Ubuntu 16.04.
Tried to connect to the ubuntu but I got an error as below.

> Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64)
>
> - Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com  * Management:
>     https://landscape.canonical.com  * Support:
>     https://ubuntu.com/advantage
>
>   Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
>     http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud
>
> 0 packages can be updated. 0 updates are security updates.
>
> /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv-init: line 131: cannot create temp
>   file for here-document: Read-only file system Connection to xxxx
>   closed.

It worked yesterday so I do not understand why it suddenly became a read-only file system.

Comment: try a vagrant reload? that will 'halt' and then 'up' the box

Comment: It worked!! But I don't understand why...
Thank you though!!

Comment: did you shut down your computer between connecting? before shutting down the host you should do a vagrant halt. i'm relatively new to vagrant, so i'm not sure.  learned the reload command and it fixed my problem, so i thought i'd share.

Comment: I logged out but did not shut down my computer..
I see, will keep that in mind! Thanks for the tip!